# Compute $\sum\limits_{i+j+k=n} x^{2i+j+k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

> How to compute for all $n\geq 1$ and all $x\in (0,1)$ the following quantity?
>   $$\sum\limits_{i+j+k=n,\\ i,j,k\geq 0} x^{2i+j+k}.$$

Comment: Are $i,j,k \in \mathbb{N}^{\geq 0}$ ?

Comment: Yes, post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We have that
\begin{align}\sum_{i+j+k=n,\\ i,j,k\geq 0} x^{2i+j+k}&=x^n\sum_{i+j+k=n,\\ i,j,k\geq 0}x^{i}=x^n\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}1
\\&=x^n\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}(n-i+1)\\
&=(n+2)x^n\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}-x^n\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)x^{i}\\
&=(n+2)x^n\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}-x^n\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i+1}\right).
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: in the second step, what happend to $k$?

Comment: Note $i+j+k=n$ and given $i$, the equation $j+k=n-i$ has $(n-i+1)$ solutions: $(j,k)=(0,n-i),(1,n-i-1),\dots(n-i,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sum is $\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i+n}=x^n\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$

Comment: There can be many more terms than $n$ in the sum of the OP.